# Как добавить колайдер объектав в blender 3.5 для экспорта в unreal engine 5?

Tags: blender, unreal-engine-5

Делаю модель в blender 3.5 для экспорта в unreal engine 5. После размещение объекта в движке вскрылось что объект упирается в невидимые стены.  Поиски в интернете привели только к тому что колайдеры выставляются в blender, но как это сделать я не знаю.
Unreal engine 5-5.0.1
Blender - 3.5